# Error with undefined variable defined within an IF statement

Tags: c, gcc, gcc4.8

When trying to compile the following snippet of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void change_a(int * a) {
    *a = 1;
    return;
}

void main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    change_a(&a);
    if (a) {
        time_t start = time(NULL);
    }
/* do something that never mentions a */

    if (a) {
        time_t end = time(NULL);
       printf("Time spent = %ld\n", (int) end - start);
    }
}
```

GCC states that the `start` variable is undefined in the `printf` line:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.8.2-1) 4.8.2
[SNIP]
$ gcc -o test.bin test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:24:44: error: ‘start’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   printf("Time spent = %ld\n", (int) end - start);
```

On the other hand, it compiles and works OK when changing the main function to:

```
void main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    time_t start = 0;

    change_a(&a);
    if (a) {
        start = time(NULL);
    }
    ...
```

### Question 1

**Am I doing something wrong or is the compiler doing something funny I don't know about?**

I think it may be the compiler being too smart and optimizing that piece of code out or having a failure in its heuristics or something. But every other time I've *"found compiler bugs"* it was always me missing some very obvious error.

So I'd rather intelligent people check this before I accuse other smart people of not being so smart. Specially when the issue also happens without optimization:

```
$ gcc -O0 -o test.bin test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:24:44: error: ‘start’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   printf("Time spent = %ld\n", (int) end - start);
                                            ^
test.c:24:44: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

### Question 2

I'd also like to know if **there is a better way to avoid the compiler error (if not the workaround in the last code snippet)**. This is kind of obvious if it is my code that is wrong (as the response would include the "correct" code), but I would also like to know how to avoid the error while someone fixes the (alleged) bug in GCC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first example, the `start` variable is declared inside the scope of the `if` statement. The variable therefore goes out of scope at the end of the code block (the closing curly brace `}`). This is definitely not a compiler bug.

Your "workaround" is the correct solution.

[See here](http://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/scope.html) for a more thorough description of how variable scope works in C/C++ (and many other languages which use C-style scoping).

Comment: See? It was me missing something obvious. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

maybe "start" scope is in 
`if (a) {
        time_t start = time(NULL);
    }`
start is cannot refernce out of if block